# How do change these email regExes to not be case sensitive?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like the following regExes to allow a user to enter their email addresses reguardless of case as long as they match for example:

linda@yahoo.com
linda@Yahoo.com

Does someone have a regEx for this?

```
emailField = new forms.InputField("tEmail", /\b[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9a-z.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b/);
emailReField = new forms.InputField("tEmailRetype", /\b[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9a-z.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b/);
```

Comment: Do you want to modify your regexes, or do you want to know how to compare two strings case insensitively?

Comment: Those regexes already are (effectively) case-insensitive -- everyplace you specify `A-Z` inside a character class, you're also specifying `a-z`. You could make them shorter by making them case-insensitive, but they already seem to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Append the `i` flag:

```
/whatever/i
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the strings to lower (or upper) case before comparing:

```
if (y.toLowerCase() === x.toLowerCase()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: ⅩⅥ: That technique is especially useful when you have to reduce both sides to one of the Unicode Normalization forms, like `NFKD(x) == NFKD(y)`.